# minimize a loss function using a specific form of the gradient of loss w.r.t its parameters

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

In machine learning, given a loss function to be minimized, we usually opt to some machine learning library to update parameter. For example, in tensorflow, we usually do the following thing, first write down loss function,

```
self.loss = F(\theta, \eta)
self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)          
self.train_op = self.optimizer.minimize(
                self.loss, global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step())
```

then use `_, loss = sess.run([self.train_op, self.loss], feed_dict)` to update parameters to minimize the loss function.

In this case, we do not need to care what the exact form of the gradient of F(\theta, \eta) w.r.t \theta and \eta is.

I want to know how to use a specific form of the gradient of loss w.r.t its parameters to update the parameters and minimize the loss. That's to say, given forms of the gradient, how to use machine learning library to write down something to update.

**Update1** @lejlot provided an amazing answer(see below) for helping this which based on first computing some `true_gradient` through Adam and then modify the gradient to what you want. However, for me, I want to know if it is possible to side step this, directly apply a desirable form of a gradient to the loss. The reason behind this is that I do not know the form of computed `true_gradients` so I can not add something to it. For example, my desirable form of the gradient is `f(\theta)`, but how to go from the computed true_gradients to `f(\theta)` is unknown since we do not know the form of the calculated `true_gradients`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is worth noting that there is just **one** proper "form" of the gradient, and it is computed automatically by libraries like TF using automatic differentiation. If you do **anything** to this gradient it is no longer a gradient of the loss function you are considering. Following it might still lead to convergence (there are many theorems showing that if the update direction is "similar enough" it will still work) but it is worth understanding that playing around with the gradient **usually will create something that is not a proper gradient of any function**. This is extremely important if one applies anything other than gradient descent as an optimiser - for example in your code you have Adam, which can break completely if what you provide is not a proper gradient (as it uses it to make second order estimates, thus they will be completely wrong if you mess with the gradient, and could even lead to divergence/random behaviour).

However, if you simply know a gradient (or have a good **mathematical** reason to believe that what you do will not break optimisation), you can just apply it directly yourself in TF by exploiting the fact that .minimize internally calls two functions: compute_gradients and apply_gradients.

So (in pseudocode) it will be sth among the lines of:

```
self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)          
true_gradients = self.optimizer.compute_gradients(self.loss)

my_own_gradients = do_some_magical_stuff_with(true_gradients)

self.train_op = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(my_own_gradients)
```

That's it!

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you! I also wanna to know if it is possible to side step the second line in the pseudocode, directly give a form of desirable gradient and apply it to loss.

Comment: The reason I want to sidestep the second line is that I do not know the form of computed `true_gradients` so I can not add something to it. For example, my desirable form of the gradient is `f(\theta)`, how to go from the computed `true_gradients` to `f(\theta)` is unknown since we do not know the form of the calculated `true_gradients`.

Comment: Oh, I suddenly understand that I can sidestep 2nd step indeed, just need to ignore 2nd step. Thanks, @lejlot!

Comment: Exactly, all you have to do is define your "do_some_magical_stuff_with" to ignore its argument :)

Comment: Thank you for helping me figure out it.  But when I need two gradients of loss w.r.t two different sets of parameters, it seems that this approach can not be directly applied to. Could you please see this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45748821/4724046). I tried a long time to figure out it but not yet succeeded.

Comment: compute_gradients accepts second argument - list of variables, just pass it twice, concatenate and apply

Comment: can `self.optimizer.apply_gradients()` accept a list of variables? since I want to sidestep `true_gradients = self.optimizer.compute_gradients(self.loss)` and directly apply my own gradients `gradient_theta` and `gradient_eta` to update `self.theta` and `self.eta` respectively.

Comment: Basically yes, I answered to your second question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152285/discussion-between-ytutow-and-lejlot).